# I need javascript to prefix+suffix as it is populating a field? I want it to be surrounded with apostrophes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, prefix

div with-altfield is a multidatepicker. Upon selection of a date it populates the altfield input. In format, mm/dd/yy,mm/dd/yy,.. I want it to actually populate the input with apostrophes surrounding the date selected. Like, 'mm/dd/yy','mm/dd/yy',... this is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(function() {
    $('#with-altField').multiDatesPicker({
        altField: '#altField',

    });;
});

</script>

</head>
<body>                          
 <div id="with-altField"></div>
 <input type="text" id="altField">
</body>
```

Please help!
Thank you
Si

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what is asked here but if you need to have ' in your string do:

```
var dates = ["'07/01/13'","'07/02/13'"];
```

or

```
var dates = ['\'07/01/13\'','\'07/02/13\''];
```

Comment: var dates only preselects dates on the calendar it doesn't effect what is added to altfield when a date is selected by the user.

When a date is selected it populates altfield, but in the wrong format I want it to be surrounded with apostrophes. thanks

Comment: ignore var dates that isn't the issue, that works perfect.  div with-altfield is a multidatepicker.  Upon selection of a date it populates the altfield input. In format, mm/dd/yy,mm/dd/yy,.. I want it to actually populate the input with apostrophes surrounding the date selected.  Like, 'mm/dd/yy','mm/dd/yy',... does that make sense? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `dateFormat: "'mm/dd/yy'"` below the `addDates` line. Don't forget to add the apostrophes to the contents of the `dates` variable, like Alex noted.

Comment: I tried that it just ignores the apostrophes... its a pain. thanks for the suggestion though. Si